# Start utterances for start bixby apllication

Tags: bixby

1. How to determine (and where???) all start utterances for bixby to interact with my capsule? Eg I want to say **start appname, play appname** etc
2. When capsule starts in emu it is not requesting for any data my code, only after some NL message - so result-view not starting. How I can start some response on capsule start auto?

Answer (score 0):

Your capsule will be invoked *ONLY* when there is a match between the end-user's utterance and the utterances in your capsule's training.

So, if you have an utterance like "Start appName" as part of your training, and the end-user says the same, then your capsule will be invoked within the simulator.

Let's say you developed a capsule OrderPizza that helps users order pizza and included "Start OrderPizza" as an utterance in your training.

```
User: Start OrderPizza
Bixby: Welcome to OrderPizza. I can help you with ordering a pizza. I noticed that you are in this <neighborhood>. Would you like to search in this region?
User: <Yes>/<No> 
...
...
...
...
```

The user is equally likely to say "I want to order a pizza" and you probably want to train OrderPizza to include that utterance which will be a potential entry point into your capsule.

It is the responsibility of the capsule developers to identify and train their capsule on all potential utterances.